# How do I start a free tier account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I try to deploy something in the gcp , the page redirects me to billing page where it says I am eligible for $300 free trial and it will automatically be started when I enter my billing info .

I do not want free trial , **I want to use free tier** .

How do I do that ? or I have to be a free trial user to use free tier . If I use a free trial account , what happens after 90 days ? Can I continue using free tier ?

Note that : Giving billing info will start free $300 trial .

Comment: You can stay with Free Tier. Watch this video to learn more about Free Tier and Free Trial: https://videolabs.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/#1

Comment: When I try to deploy my VM it asks me for billing info and verification . And forces me to start trial .

Answer (score 0):

When you first sign into GCP, they will always offer you the free trial first so that you try all the products you may be interested in without any cost.

However, you can use the the free tier resources during the free trial, and keep using them once the free trial has ended. You can find more information about this on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier).

Keep in mind that you need to stay in the [Free Tier usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/free/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=emea-pl-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-gcp-1010042&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_482046654175-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20BKWS%20-%20EXA%20%7C%20Txt%20%7E%20GCP%20%7E%20Trial%23v11-KWID_43700059014042880-kwd-310728589823-userloc_9067405&utm_term=KW_gcp%20free%20tier-NET_g-PLAC_&gclid=Cj0KCQjw6NmHBhD2ARIsAI3hrM3o-VIts7gsWnfJnZQBB5I7DO53_5_wLHwoUfmdM9pH_EohbuNLYAcaAr08EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) so that you do not get billed for the usage, in order to ensure this, I would recommend you to add some set up a budget on your project.

Comment: When I try to deploy my VM it asks me for billing info and verification . And forces me to start trial .

Comment: Yes, this is normal as in case you exceed the usage of the free tier, you would need to be billed for the excedent usage and that would go against your free trial credits.